# TDE indexing based on context?

Tags: sql, marklogic, tde

I have a requirement to create the TDE to generate views. The data volume is huge. But I need to create conetxt of template on root node. So how big the performance/indexing size impact by creating on root node, which will match to all the docs in DB(size in TB).

XML has more than 100 elements...

Comment: Every doc that matches will get indexed. The impact regarding performance, size, etc. depends upon how big/complex your TDE are, how large your database is, and how many nodes and what resources they have available.